# Fitnesse login test

Tags: java, junit, automated-tests, jenkins-pipeline, fitnesse

I'm working on a delivery pipeline. I want to integrate multiple test-automation frameworks in it. One of them is Fitnesse. On the web I see lots of examples that test a Java class using the wikiserver. But what I don't see is if it is possible to test a simple (jsp) login form. Also I want to start this test from within a Juni test, without installing the wikiserver. Just adding the Fitnesse maven dependcency.

Is there anyone who can give me an example of how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please try some code yourself first.

Comment: I've tried a lot already, as I said, writing a Fitnesse test that tests a Java method in combination with a wiki server is no problem. But can't find any starting point for what I need

Comment: What you probably want is [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/), or some [Fitnesse web-plugins](http://www.fitnesse.org/PlugIns#slimfixtures) for Selenium. But based on your description it's [JUnit+Selenium](http://www.baeldung.com/java-selenium-with-junit-and-testng)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems to be twofold:

- how do I write a FitNesse test for a login web page, and:
- how do I run this test inside a delivery pipeline (where I want it to act as a
  jUnit test)

From your question it is not really clear to me whether you already managed to write the test you are looking for. Like mentioned in comments to your question: FitNesse itself does not offer any way to test a web form directly. You either need to write your own code to connect the wiki to the web page to be tested (a fixture) or use a library which contains such a fixture.

To run a FitNesse test inside a delivery pipeline, like a jUnit test, you can write a jUnit test with a `RunWith` annotation and then specifying FitNesse's `FitNesseRunner`. Something like the test below from [FitNesse's own tests](https://github.com/unclebob/fitnesse/blob/master/test/fitnesse/junit/FitNesseRunnerTest.java):

```
package fitnesse.junit;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(FitNesseRunner.class)
@FitNesseRunner.Suite("FitNesse.SuiteAcceptanceTests.SuiteSlimTests.TestScriptTable")
@FitNesseRunner.FitnesseDir(".")
@FitNesseRunner.OutputDir("./build/fitnesse-results")
public class FitNesseRunnerTest {
}
```

---

I've create an [(open source) project](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures#hsac-fitnesse-fixtures) which contains both fixtures to use a web login form (either via a browser, with Selenium, or directly send a http POST to the server) and to run tests you define in the wiki from a build server (providing a jUnit test which you can configure to run a specific test/suite by adding a system property). So if you don't have a setup yet, that might be a good starting point.

Using that project a login form test (for instance called MyTests.LoginTest) might look something like:

```
|script|browser test|
|open|https://example.com/myprofile|
|enter|johndoe|as|Username|
|enter|secret|as|Password|
|click|Login|
|check|value of|Firstname|John|
|check|value of|Lastname|Doe|
```

And the call to run test (using Maven), which would be embedded in your pipeline:

```
mvn clean test-compile failsafe:integration-test -DfitnesseSuiteToRun=MyTests.LoginTest -DseleniumGridUrl=http://${SAUCE_USERNAME}:${SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY}@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub -DseleniumCapabilities="browserName:chrome,platform:Windows 7,screenResolution:1680x1050"
```

Comment: Hi Fried,

You're right. It is a two folded question. As this is completely new for me it is difficult to explain what exact I want.   Youré solution seems what to be what I'm looking for. First I want to run the test via the wikiserver buit then I get this message: __EXCEPTION__:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LoginTest (wrong name:  
And  in the next step I see the message: The instance scriptTableActor.open. does not exist

Comment: It sounds like your setup is not quite right yet. Always a bit of a hassle. Have you tried taking the sample project using my project and seeing whether the sample wiki pages below HsacExamples.SlimTests.BrowserTests

work for you? Try modifying one of those for your login page.

Comment: No haven't yet. Not sure if i'm allowed to download it on the office:(
At the moment I've launched fitnesse by using the stand-alone.jar. Can this be an issue?

Comment: That is definitely an issue. With only fitnesse's standalone jar you will need to write your own Java code for the fixtures and setup selenium.

Comment: I made some progress  and can get a simple working.
Problem now is that when i use |open|https://example.com/myprofile| in my wiki, my fixture receives : <a href="https://example.com/myprofile/">https://example.com/myprofile/</a>

Comment: That is a completely new question as far as I'm concerned. Either place !- -! around the URL in the wiki, or clean up the value in your fixture (my fixtures use the latter approach)

Comment: Thanks that worked. Any particular reason why you resolved the url in your fixture?

Comment: I don't like forcing users to escape stuff. And I do like clickable web addresses.